# Qt - image-link

Tags: c++, image, qt, hyperlink

How to place an image on a QWidget that will open a browser and go to Google when you click on the picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handle the `mousePressEvent` and then open the link using `QDesktopServices::openUrl`.

Comment: It works fine. Only mouse does not change its shape (need to become a hand) whan it's on the picture.

Comment: Just need to be added myQWidget->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor); and it is perfect!